# Error Message Display - Form Data PHP Entry in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Currently, we have a PHP Form that uses an entry for a redirect to Private sites within our main website, of which code we use the following:

```
<?php
//Turn the content from text box into variable
$page=$_POST['text'];

if($_POST['text']=='sit') {
//set up a redirect to that page
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/index.php/private/sit\">";

}

else if($_POST['text']=='pony') {
//set up a redirect to that page
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/client/pony/index.html\">";

}
```

Originally, we had implemented a final line that if someone inserted something wrong, it would refresh the page:

```
else {
   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://example.com\">";

}
?>
```

How to show a message that says "Error" in Bold and Red next to the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline Active Javascript Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197458/inline-active-javascript-form-validation)

Comment: Why not just echo out an element with a specific class, and then apply CSS styling to that class?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a parameter in the URL you use to refresh. And then check on the parameter after the URL refresh by Javascript and add the error.

In this case you will echo something like this instead

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"0;URL=http://example.com?error=1\">";
```

Then in your html, use Javascript or PHP to check on the URL param and render error with style.